# $mysqli->affected_rows returns -1, but $mysqli->errno returns 0

Tags: php, mysqli

I am programming a php program which needs to connect mysql.
So I try to use mysqli. But I got a question as the title says.
For the detail is like this:

```
<?php
....
        $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        $sql = "update dsagencyinfo set Company='a', Region='b', AgencyName='c', HeadAgencyCode='71u269', AgencyFlag='4850G', AgencyStarts='dd', AgencyAttr='e', AgencyType='test', AgencyAddr='f1', AgencyPhoto='ss', HouseAttr='f', HouseArea='60', DecorationDate='41183', CounterNumber='6', CounterNumberLT='2', CounterNumberYD='5', OperatorName='dd', OperatorTel='18607277068', ClerkNumber='1', AdminName='ff', AdminTel='1860727123',  CreateTime=now() where AgencyCode=36578689  ";
        if($mysqli->query($sql)){
           if($mysqli->affected_rows == 1){
               return true;
           }else{
               return false;
           }

        }
?>
```

But I then find that `$mysqli->affected_rows` returns -1, that is to say, there should be something wrong with this sql, so I get the value of `$mysqli->errno`, but it returns 0 which indicates there's no error happening! And still, `$mysqli->error` also returns "".
Then I type this sql to mysql (I use phpmyadmin), execute it and mysql says it's ok ,and I check that in database, this data is indeed updated.
I can't understand why `$mysqli->affected_rows` returns -1, and how can I solve this question?

my PHP version is 5.4.12
MySQL Version :5.6.12

Comment: Where are you outputting affected_rows so that you know it's -1? I only see the check to see if it's 1. I think there is some context missing here.

Comment: It's a part of my code.I debug it in IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the object $mysqli is not getting the result before entering in the conditional. Try:

```
if($mysqli = $mysqli->query($sql)){
       if($mysqli->affected_rows == 1){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
}
```

Or get it out of the $mysqli->query() conditional.

```
$mysqli->query($sql);
if($mysqli->affected_rows == 1){
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you though you didn't solve my question, but you give me an important idea.This happens not because the $mysqli->query, but $mysqli->affected_rows. I modified my code like this which solved my question (I am still not very clear why this happened): if($mysqli->query($sql)){  
           $row = $mysqli->affected_rows;  
           if($row == 1){//$mysqli->affected_rows here still returns -1  
               return true;  
           }else{  
               return false;  
           }  
        }

Comment: Did you try to do $mysqli->affected_rows outside of the $mysqli->query() conditional?

Comment: Wait, `$mysqli = $mysqli->query($sql)` => overwrite a mysqli object with a boolean? Why would you want that?

Comment: no , I just tried to use a variable $row to store $mysqli->affected_rows right after $mysqli->query($sql), and then put $row to the 'if' conditional like if($row == 1) instead of  if($mysqli->affected_rows == 1) , and it worked.

Comment: Great. As Wrikken mentioned you have your mysqli object response, what i did it was a quick fix, but **NEVER** the correct aproach. Thanks.